# Unparseable date at offset 0

Tags: android

here's my code

```
private Time today;
private String currentDateTime;
private static String dateTimeFormatting = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";

today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();
        currentDateTime = today.format(dateTimeFormatting);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormatting);
        currentDateTimeFormatted = sdf.parse(currentDateTime);
```

and it will return this error:

```
Error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15-03-12 18:21:06" (at offset 0)
```

From what I see, my formatting is declared rightly inside the dateTimeFormatting right? So why still an error?

Comment: Did you try the format like ``"YY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS"``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the syntax accepted by the `SimpleDateFormat` is different from the syntax of `Time`, is also good practice when dealing with times and dates to provide an appropriate `Locale` reference.

```
private Time today;
private String currentDateTime;
private static String dateTimeFormatting = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";
private static String simpleDateFormatting = "yy-MM-DD HH:mm:SS"

today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
currentDateTime = today.format(dateTimeFormatting);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(simpleDateFormatting, Locale.getDefault());
currentDateTimeFormatted = sdf.parse(currentDateTime);
```

Comment: now I got this error message "Error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)"

Comment: sorry @Edo b it works actually. the empty currentDateTime is actually from another variable. thanks!